# Json D3 array contents not working

Tags: json, d3.js

The attached code should produce a few coloured circles, and indeed it does when using a hard-coded dataset of `[1,4,2,3,5]`.

However, I don't understand why the code below isn't working using my JSON data array.

The console in the browser is showing the JSON query is successfully running and pulling the data into the page - just nothing seems to happen with it.

The JSON query is as follows:

```
[{"Id":1,"UserID":"JNP","HCRef":"ProjSetup","AnswerString":"","Answerlist":1},
{"Id":2,"UserID":"JNP","HCRef":"ProjSetup","AnswerString":null,"Answerlist":2},
{"Id":3,"UserID":"JNP","HCRef":"ProjSetup","AnswerString":null,"Answerlist":5},
{"Id":4,"UserID":"JNP","HCRef":"ProjSetup","AnswerString":null,"Answerlist":6},
{"Id":5,"UserID":"JNP","HCRef":"ProjSetup","AnswerString":null,"Answerlist":3},
{"Id":6,"UserID":"JNP","HCRef":null,"AnswerString":null,"Answerlist":4}]
```

What I want to happen, is use the `Answerlist` variable to be returned in the `returncolour` section of the code and drive the colour of the circles. The data is otherwise only used to trigger a circle being drawn at all (using the 'i' parameter).

As I say, the code works fine doing this with a hardcoded dataset.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataset = d3.json('/api/answers/', function (d) {
        console.log(d);
    });

    var w = 1000;
    var h = 1000;
    // var dataset = [1,4,2,3,5];
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);
    var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
             .data(dataset)
             .enter()
             .append("circle");

    circles.attr("cx", function (d, i) 
    {
        var Xaxis;
        if (i === 0) { Xaxis = "500"; }
        else if (i === 1) { Xaxis = "400"; }
        else if (i === 2) { Xaxis = "420"; }
        else if (i === 3) { Xaxis = "452.5"; }
        else if (i === 4) { Xaxis = "485"; }
        else if (i === 5) { Xaxis = "515"; }
        else if (i === 6) { Xaxis = "547.5"; }
        else if (i === 7) { Xaxis = "580"; }
        else if (i === 8) { Xaxis = "600"; }
        else if (i === 9) { Xaxis = "600"; }
        else if (i === 10) { Xaxis = "650"; }
        else if (i === 11) { Xaxis = "700"; }
        else if (i === 12) { Xaxis = "750"; }
        else if (i === 13) { Xaxis = "750"; }
        else if (i === 14) { Xaxis = "750"; }
        else if (i === 15) { Xaxis = "750"; }
        else if (i === 16) { Xaxis = "750"; }
        return Xaxis;
    })
    circles.attr("cy", function (d, i) {
        var Yaxis;
        if (i === 0) { Yaxis = "500"; }
        else if (i === 1) { Yaxis = "500"; }
        else if (i === 2) { Yaxis = "535"; }
        else if (i === 3) { Yaxis = "560"; }
        else if (i === 4) { Yaxis = "585"; }
        else if (i === 5) { Yaxis = "585"; }
        else if (i === 6) { Yaxis = "560"; }
        else if (i === 7) { Yaxis = "535"; }
        else if (i === 8) { Yaxis = "500"; }
        else if (i === 9) { Yaxis = "600"; }
        else if (i === 10) { Yaxis = "550"; }
        else if (i === 11) { Yaxis = "500"; }
        else if (i === 12) { Yaxis = "450"; }
        else if (i === 13) { Yaxis = "600"; }
        else if (i === 14) { Yaxis = "550"; }
        else if (i === 15) { Yaxis = "500"; }
        else if (i === 16) { Yaxis = "450"; }
        return Yaxis;
    })
   .attr("r", function (d, i) {
       var size;
       if (i === 0) { size = "30"; }
       else if (i > 0) { size = "20"; }
       return size;
   })
   .attr("fill", function (d) {
       return d.Answerlist;
       var returnColor;
       if (d.Answerlist === 1) { returnColor = "green"; }
       else if (d.Answerlist === 2) { returnColor = "lightgreen"; }
       else if (d.Answerlist === 3) { returnColor = "gold"; }
       else if (d.Answerlist === 4) { returnColor = "darkorange"; }
       else if (d.Answerlist === 5) { returnColor = "red"; }
       else if (d.Answerlist === 6) { returnColor = "lightgrey"; }
        return returnColor;
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to asynchronous code.

Move your processing code inside the callback, where you currently only have:

```
console.log(d);
```

The code you will put there is executed later than any of the non-callback code you have, because the script first executes to completion and only *then* (asynchronously) the callback will be fired -- and thus, only *then* `d` (`dataset`) will have the desired value:

```
d3.json('/api/answers/', function (dataset) {
    var w = 1000;
    var h = 1000;
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);
    var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
             .data(dataset)
             .enter()
             .append("circle");
    // etc....
    // ...
});
```

NB: your enormous `if` statements can be reduced to 5% of the code, if you would use arrays for your possible values.

For instance, this:

```
    var Xaxis;
    if (i === 0) { Xaxis = "500"; }
    else if (i === 1) { Xaxis = "400"; }
    else if (i === 2) { Xaxis = "420"; }
    else if (i === 3) { Xaxis = "452.5"; }
    else if (i === 4) { Xaxis = "485"; }
    else if (i === 5) { Xaxis = "515"; }
    else if (i === 6) { Xaxis = "547.5"; }
    else if (i === 7) { Xaxis = "580"; }
    else if (i === 8) { Xaxis = "600"; }
    else if (i === 9) { Xaxis = "600"; }
    else if (i === 10) { Xaxis = "650"; }
    else if (i === 11) { Xaxis = "700"; }
    else if (i === 12) { Xaxis = "750"; }
    else if (i === 13) { Xaxis = "750"; }
    else if (i === 14) { Xaxis = "750"; }
    else if (i === 15) { Xaxis = "750"; }
    else if (i === 16) { Xaxis = "750"; }
    return Xaxis;
```

... can be written as:

```
    var Xaxis = [500, 400, 420, 452.5, 485, 515, 547.5, 580, 600, 600,
                 650, 700, 750, 750,   750,  750, 750][i];
```

It seems though you want to position the smaller circles nicely around the bigger circle. In that case you can calculate the coordinates using trigonometric functions (sine and cosine) based on the value of *i*. It could look like this for the smaller circles (`i > 0`) -- the larger is positioned at `[x,y] = [500,500]`:

```
    x = 500-Math.cos((i-1)/2)*100
    y = 500+Math.sin((i-1)/2)*100
```

Also note that you have dead code in your `attr` callback. The `return` statement will exit that function before determining a color and returning that. So you should delete that `return` statement.

Finally, there is a color missing, since your sample data has `AnswerList` values going up to 6, while you only specify colors for up to index 5.

Here is how the code could look with these changes. Note that I have used ES6 arrow functions. If you don't have ES6 support, just change them to standard functions:

```js
var dataset = [
    {"Id":1,"UserID":"JNP","HCRef":"ProjSetup","AnswerString":"","Answerlist":1},
    {"Id":2,"UserID":"JNP","HCRef":"ProjSetup","AnswerString":null,"Answerlist":2},
    {"Id":3,"UserID":"JNP","HCRef":"ProjSetup","AnswerString":null,"Answerlist":5},
    {"Id":4,"UserID":"JNP","HCRef":"ProjSetup","AnswerString":null,"Answerlist":6},
    {"Id":5,"UserID":"JNP","HCRef":"ProjSetup","AnswerString":null,"Answerlist":3},
    {"Id":6,"UserID":"JNP","HCRef":null,"AnswerString":null,"Answerlist":4}];
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 1000)
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", (d, i) => i ? 500-Math.cos((i-1)/2)*100 : 500)
    .attr("cy", (d, i) => i ? 500+Math.sin((i-1)/2)*100 : 500)
    .attr("r", (d, i) => i === 0 ? 30 : 20)
    .attr("fill", (d) => ['', 'green', 'gold', 'darkorange', 'red', 'lightgrey', 'purple']
                         [d.Answerlist]);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
Scroll down to see the colored circles.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have given this a go and still no joy. The Console still shows the object values being loaded, but the code doesn't seem to be doing anything with the data. I am suspecting that something is wrong with how I am calling the right part of the Json string to be used.

Should I be doing something different to call the Answerlist section of the Json string, as that is where the Int values sit that will determine the colour.

Comment: Well, I don't know why you put a `return` statement at the start of the `fill` callback (near the end), but if you want to see colors, then you might want to enable the code you have below that `return`: just remove it, so the color is being read from the dataset. I don't know what else you expect to happen.

Comment: I added a working snippet for your convenience. I also added a better solution for placing the smaller circles nicely around the bigger one.

Comment: I have spent some time looking at this - firstly, yes I can now see the mistake on the premature return statement! Silly indeed. However, I have tried running your code on my build and no joy. I have also tried removing the return and tweaking etc, I still just get a blank unless I use hardcoded data rather than the JSON. I will keep looking at it, but cannot see why the JSON string isn't playing ball.

Comment: Make sure *all* the code that is processing the dataset is in the callback of this statement: `d3.json('/api/answers/', function (dataset) { // here });`. If the dataset is like you say it is, then there is no reason why it should not work, provided you stay within the scope of that callback function.

Comment: Yes 100% sure the code is within the { } now. The dataset is copied directly from the JSON file if I download it through the browser. In the Console there is a more complicated object structure being shown, but I am assuming that is just the way the Console works and not that the data is being built in some odd way

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle that demonstrates the problem? For better debugging, write the JSON representation to the console: `console.log(JSON.stringify(dataset));` and carefully check it has the structure you expect.

Comment: That was useful, the Console not logs the JSON string and it is showing exactly how I would expect: [{"Id":1,"UserID":"JNP","HCRef":"ProjSetup","AnswerString":"","Answerlist":1},{"Id":2,"UserID":"JNP","HCRef":"ProjSetup","AnswerString":null,"Answerlist":2},{"Id":3,"UserID":"JNP","HCRef":"ProjSetup","AnswerString":null,"Answerlist":5},{"Id":4,"UserID":"JNP","HCRef":"ProjSetup","AnswerString":null,"Answerlist":6},{"Id":5,"UserID":"JNP","HCRef":"ProjSetup","AnswerString":null,"Answerlist":3},{"Id":6,"UserID":"JNP","HCRef":null,"AnswerString":null,"Answerlist":4}]

Comment: So, if you now assign to `dataset` this exact object literal, at the place where you perform this `console.log`, then it should still not work. If this is indeed the case, can you create a JSFiddle so we can see that it does not work and debug? There must be something different than I have posted, because as you can see, it works in my snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, and the problem with the asynchronous code was already solved by trincot. But I'd like to talk about your huge and unnecessary `if else` statements. It was also addressed in trincot's answer, but there is an even better *D3 way*  of dealing with it: using [scales](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale).

So, if you want to positioning your circles evenly from the position 200 to the position 400 in your x axis, here is a simple solution:

```
var xScale = d3.scalePoint()
    .range([200, 400])//the start and end position
```

Then, you use the scale to set the circles' `cx` position:

```
.attr("cx", function(d,i){
    return xScale(i)
});
```

See? You don't need to manually set the x positions in a huge array (`[400, 420, 450...]`) and even less in a cumbersome bunch of `if` statements, d3 does that for you.

Check this demo, using 10 circles:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 100);

var dataset = d3.range(10);

var xScale = d3.scalePoint()
    .range([200, 400])
    .domain(dataset);

var circles = svg.selectAll(".circle")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("circle");

circles.attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("fill", "teal")
  .attr("cx", function(d,i){return xScale(i)});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but per your previous help, this code will not use IF statements like this in the final version, I am simply used this code to test the connection to the database and use the Json string - so I appreciate the messy IF statements aren't good.

Would you be able to look at the other question I have posted, which is using your previous advice with regard to generating the circles? What I will then do, is use the working Json array code from this question with the smarter circle solution.

I didn't want to mix up the questions here etc.

Comment: @JNPer Did you see my last comment in your first question?